# Ambiguous result date java

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

i'm retrieving a strange result:

First i get current date using `GregorianCalendar`:

```
GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
int m = g.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int d = g.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int y = g.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Then i create new object `Date`:

```
Date d = new Date(d,m,y);
```

Then i print them together in this way:

```
System.out.println(d+" - "+m+" - "+y+" - "+d);
```

and i get:

```
1 - 18 - 2012 - Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 1908
```

can you explain me why? is for deprecated method `Date(day,mouth,year)` ? 
if yes, how can i compare two Date using that parameters?

Comment: `Date d = new Date(d,m,y);` ?  No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then i create new object Date:
>
> ```
> Date d = new Date(d,m,y);
> ```

The order of the arguments to the constructor is `year`, `month`, `date`, nothing else.

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> `Date(int year, int month, int day)`

> how can i compare two Date using that parameters?

Depends on *how* you want to compare two `Date`s. If you just want to figure out which comes first, you could use `Date.before` and `Date.after`.

But as you've noted, the `Date` class is **deprecated**. Use the `Calendar` class instead, (or better yet, the [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/))

Answer (score 1):

If you need to obtain a new `Date` object from a `GregorianCalendar`, do this:

```
Date d = g.getTime();
```

In this way, you won't have to use deprecated methods, and the result will be the one you expect. Also, if you need to obtain the current date, simply write `new Date()`, no need for a `GregorianCalendar`.

As far as date comparisons go, you can use `Date`'s `compareTo()`, `after()` and `before()` methods. Again, there's no need for a `GregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Calendar, then set the time using the Date object, then you can get any information you need from it.

Example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
// and so on....
```

Comment: If your locale uses the Gregorian Calendar, Calendar.getInstance() will return a GregorianCalendar instance... if you are not sure, just do Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); You can even do new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day), and then get a Date object by calling the Calendar's method getTime().